# Generalizing get operation in selenium test

Tags: java, selenium, generics

I am trying to create a automatic test for a webpage. Webpage has a filter form and a table. Table has 5-6 different ways to present data.

I have created PageObjects for each of the data presenting ways(All are tables just with different columns). Now i have this generic Pageobject that can find the table and ask the rows from it.

But i cannot get working the pece of code to fetch all the rows of the table.

```
public <T> List<T> getAllRows(){
        List<AbstractTableRow> allRows = table.findElements(By.xpath("//tr[@role='row']").className("jqgrow")).stream()
            .map(AbstractTableRow::new).collect(Collectors.toList());
        if(allRows != null) {
            return (List<T>)allRows;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

AbstractTableRow is the parent for all the other rows. But its not actually abstract class(I tryed that way and ended up in the messy business of generics + reflections that didnt end up working). So now I need someway to downcast parent to child, or can someone give an example with reflections and generics that would work(Then i can make AbstratTableRow abstract again). All the tablerows come in as type WebElement and all rowobject have

```
public SomeRow(WebElement element)
```

as constructor. Method needs to return List where SomeRow is one of the 5-6 row types.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need a factory class that produces objects that implement TableRow interface (or extend abstract AbstractTableRow class).

This is usually done in this way:

```
public interface TableRow {
  /*methods..*/
}

public class NiceRow implements TableRow {
  public NiceRow(WebElement element) {
    //implementation
  }
  /*Implementation..*/
}

public class CuteRow implements TableRow {
  public CuteRow(WebElement element) {
    //implementation
  }
  /*Implementation..*/
}

public class TableRowFactory {
  public static TableRow getRow(WebElement element) {
    switch(element.getAttribute("class")) {
      case "nice":
        return new NiceRow(element);
      /*...*/
    }
  }
}
```

Now you can get a factory object and use it to produce rows:

```
TableRowFactory factory = new TableRowFactory();
List<TableRow> allRows = 
    table.findElements(By.xpath("//tr[@role='row']")).stream()
      .map(element -> factory.getRow(element))
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**EDIT**:
 Please note that getAttribute("class") will most probably produce something more than just a single class and is in my code only for example purposes of distinguishing between classes.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the class of the `concrete SomeRow type`. Also you can switch the RowTable to abstract which will contain a constructor with WebElement as single parameter which will get overloaded in subtypes. (I think this is already present).

```
public static <T extends RowTable> List<T> getTableData(Class<T> clz) throws Exception {

            List<WebElement> elems = .....Your query....;
            Constructor<T> cont = clz.getConstructor(WebElement.class);

            List<T> data = elems.stream().map(e -> {
                T type = null;
                try {
                    type = cont.newInstance(e);
                } catch (Exception e1) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e1);
                }           
                return type;
            }).collect(Collectors.toList());

            return data;
        }
```

Call it like - `getTableData(ConcreteRow.class)`

Comment: Seems like the same result can be achieved with just doing "map(ConcreteRow::new)" in the code from the question. A bit confusing which problems exactly does all this (not very readable generic+reflection) logic solves?